# Twilio Programmable voice on Android/iOS - Passing custom information when making a call

Tags: mobile, parameters, sdk, twilio, voice

Using the twilio mobile SDK on Android/iOS, to make a voice call to support operators at the backend (purely voip, no phone at either end. Support operators will be using a backend web app that uses the twilio api/twiml to receive and queue calls)

We have one very important requirement -- to be able to pass the user-id from the mobile app to the backend when placing the call. This is required for the backend web-app to be able to automatically pull up the user's information for the support operator who picks up the call in-browser.

Is this possible with the mobile SDK by any method? Any insight would be appreciated

Edit: Can I perhaps use this user-id as the callerid parameter when dialling, and have it read at the web-app side?

Comment: PS: I have seen ways to do this with the twilio javascript API for web clients, but not sure if there is an equivalent way with Android/iOS

Comment: How have you seen it be done on web?

Comment: Quoting _Client (JavaScript)
Twilio.Device.connect() has an optional params argument which allows for a JavaScript object to be passed to the application as POST/GET parameters.

For example, the following code will pass the params app=Support and location=Seattle to the Twilio application associated with this Device's capability token.

var connection = Twilio.Device.connect({ app:"Support", location:"Seattle"});_

Comment: Thanks. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51909313/7069816). Any clues?

Comment: Cant you just add params [here](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/blob/37f564d1ce6ed1169aed190325a5fd28282c9722/SwiftVoiceQuickstart/ViewController.swift#L95) I see a `params` here too

Comment: @AbSin Think I figured out my issue. I will pass the client identity when getting an access token. Then when I use the access token at the /voice endpoint, I get the client identity -- which can contain the user-id. So I just need to respond to it at that point

Comment: PS: You can use the same method
'The Identity of the Participant generating this event. Participant identities are set via the Participant's Access Token'

So mapping the participant identity to the sid is possible using the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of working with Twilio functions, I came up with the following solution.

1. Mobile app gets access token, hits the Twilio voice endpoint, is routed to the queue, wait music plays etc.
2. Operator (web app) gets access token, hits the Twilio voice endpoint, and automatically dequeues the first caller from the queue (i.e is connected to them)
3. In the TwiML for the operator dequeuing, there is a parameter `url` which is a TwiML URL that will be fetched and executed on the queued caller's end before the caller is connected to the operator. Twilio passes a bunch of parameters to this URL, including the caller identity and the operator's call sid
4. We will host this URL at our backend, and store a map of {caller identity, operator call sid}.
5. The operator web app will poll the backend once the operator dials, until the caller identity corresponding to the current operator call sid is returned. Or the backend can send some kind of push notification to the operator web app. This is up to the implementation (we will use websockets)

For more info please see https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue

Edit - Twilio javascript API 1.5 supports access tokens instead of capability tokens, so it is simpler to use them for both mobile app and web app.

Edit 2 - Tested this flow today and works fine :-)

Comment: Now deployed in our pre-production code and working fine! In case anybody wants to use this in future.