# Twilio Programmable video - Custom information when a participant joins a room

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

So there is a webhook for [STATUS CALLBACKS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks). I was wondering if I can add custom parameters to this callback especially when a participant joins. I need to know which user gets assigned which participant id. I am using [video-quickstart-js](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js). Would be great to have it somewhere [here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/5242f6646cdedb56cb5ab990b80253f68a50efff/quickstart/src/index.js#L89)?

Comment: Any updates to this question? Is there a way to send custom information in status callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

In the callback when you get a join-event and get the sid of a participant joining, did you try using the Participant API to look up the participant by their sid?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/participants

As I see it, there is a necessary change to the video quickstart for you to be able to work with identity passed from client side -

```
// Obtain a token from the server in order to connect to the Room.
$.getJSON('/token', function(data) {
identity = data.identity;
```

You can modify the url to `/token?identity=<whatever>`. Then at the `/token` handler, you would use the identity to generate the token.

Hope this helps